# How add new row in datagrid (source in datatable)

Tags: c#, wpf

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("id");
  dt.Columns.Add("Name");

  dt.Rows.Add("1","John");
  dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
}
```

how i can add new row, on click my button? thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

**Sample Code :**

Dynamically create table, add cloumn, add rows

**1- Create a new DataTable**

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable ("Table_AX");
```

**2- Add columns to the DataTable**

```
// Method 1 
dt.Columns.Add ("column0", System.Type.GetType ("System.String")); 
// Method 2 
DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("column1",System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean")); 
dt.Columns.Add (dc);
```

**3- To add rows to the DataTable**

```
// Initialize the row 
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow (); 
dr ["column0"] = "AX"; 
dr ["column1"] = true; 
dt.Rows.Add (dr); 
// Doesn't initialize the row 
DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow (); 
dt.Rows.Add (dr1);
```

---

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("id",System.Type.GetType ("System.String"));
  dt.Columns.Add("Name",System.Type.GetType ("System.String"));
  DataRow dr=dt.NewROw();
  dr[0]="a";
  dr[1]="abc";
  dt.Rows.Add(dr);
  dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     dt.Columns.Add("id");
     dt.Columns.Add("Name");
     DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

     dr["id"]="testid";
     dr["Name"] = "testname";

     dt.Rows.Add(dr);
     dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

}
```