# DataTable last row as the first?

Tags: c#, datatable, rows, datarow

So I have a snippet of the code here that works except for one line which is the InsertAt() part. I would like to know if it is possible to copy the last row and insert it as the first. Think of the idea as this. It probably can be done in the SQL alone behind it but this application is designed to work for both a very old database and oracle so until the system migrates entirely it has to be done like this, unfortunately.

Prior

- Shipment Location 1
- Shipment Location 2
- Shipment Location 2

After

- Start Location
- Shipment Location 1
- Shipment Location 2
- Shipment Location 3
- Destination Location

The code snippet:

```
// Create a DataTable with a list of shipments.    
DataTable dt = c.Query(c.qShipments(Row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()));
// Check if there is at least one shipment
if (dt.Rows.Count >= 1)
{
    // Add the destination of the shipments
    dt.Rows.Add(0, 0, 9999, textBox_CC.Text, textBox_PC.Text, textBox_SL.Text);
    // Add the starting location (which is the same as the destination. It has to be at the top of the DataTable
    dt.Rows.InsertAt(dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1], 0); // The code

    // Finally calculate and return the object to populate the datagridview with.
    dataGridView_CalculatedRoutes.Rows.Add(x.getRoute(dt));
}
```

tldr;

Issue: Code returns Row belongs to another table.

Question: How to get the last row to be the first aswell?

Edit question: How to get the last row to be both the first and the last row. (Identical rows)

Comment: This gives the last row `DataRow last = table.Rows[table.Rows.Count - 1];`

Comment: I have tried that and even tried to change one of "last"'s values. But it keeps returning already belongs to this datatable

Comment: hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11882936/how-add-new-row-in-datagrid-source-in-datatable/11882995#11882995

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new `DataTable` and import the rows in the order that you want:

```
// Create a DataTable with a list of shipments.    
DataTable dt = c.Query(c.qShipments(Row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()));
// Check if there is at least one shipment
if (dt.Rows.Count >= 1)
{
    DataTable customDt = new DataTable();

    // Add the starting location (which is the same as the destination. It has to be at 
    customDt.Rows.Add(0, 0, 9999, textBox_CC.Text, textBox_PC.Text, textBox_SL.Text);

    foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        customDt.ImportRow(row);
    }
    // Add the destination of the shipments
    customDt.ImportRow(customDt.Rows[0]);

    // Finally calculate and return the object to populate the datagridview with.
    dataGridView_CalculatedRoutes.Rows.Add(x.getRoute(dt));
}
```

Comment: This may potentially be an even better solution. I didn't know the was an ImportRow function. I'll weight the solutions and pick either.

Comment: This works absolutely amazing and it feels clean too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The row you want to add is already part of that datatable. You would have to remove it first. In a short test I discovered that removing a row seems to delete the data in that row, so `Remove()` and `InsertAt()` don't seem to work.

But you can create a new row, copy the data to that row and insert it. After that you can delete the old row. For instance (tested using Linqpad):

```
void Main() 
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Test", typeof(System.String)));
    var row = dt.NewRow();
    row["Test"] = "1";
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
    row = dt.NewRow();
    row["Test"] = "2";
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
    row = dt.NewRow();
    row["Test"] = "3";
    dt.Rows.Add(row);

    Console.WriteLine("Order before Remove/InsertAt");
    foreach(DataRow rw in dt.Rows)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(rw["Test"]);
    }

    var lastRow = dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1];
    var newFirstRow = dt.NewRow();
    newFirstRow.ItemArray = lastRow.ItemArray;
    dt.Rows.Remove(lastRow);
    dt.Rows.InsertAt(newFirstRow, 0);

    Console.WriteLine("Order after Remove/InsertAt");
    foreach(DataRow rw in dt.Rows)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(rw["Test"]);
    }
}
```

the expected output is:

```
Order before Remove/InsertAt
1
2
3
Order after Remove/InsertAt
3
1
2
```

Comment: The output intended is supposed to be 1 2 3 to x 1 2 3 x. They're idential rows.

Comment: @DavideNguyen: Okay so you want to enter two record one for first and second for last ?

Comment: @DavideNguyen this is just an example. If you just modify my example by removing the Remove()-command, you will get 3123 as the output, which is basically what you want. You'd just have to adopt it to your own code...

Comment: Ah, I think I see the difference now! Thanks, I'll get on this!